# displaying gstreamer with opencv

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I'm wondering if it's possible to capture a frame with gstreamer and display it with opencv, or if there is anyone has a trick to do the equivalent of cvWaitKey in gstreamer (or some other library) 
Any help would be more than appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an Appsink in your pipeline to get buffers (eventually use tee ! queue ! appsink). Then you could use the image in the buffer with opencv functions if you like.

Comment: I try and I get video feed for <=1 second. It does go into the function which handles the cvShowImage, looping just like it's supposed to, then the feed freezes. It's still looping while it's frozen. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am only guessing now, but please read about buffer dropping in appsink. It sounds like you are not dequeing fast enough.